# Recurring yearly appointments created using Google API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am working on Open Source app to synchronize calendars between Google and Outlook. Some users reported some strange behavior for recurring appointments with start date years ago.  Below there is sample code, all asserts are passing. My question is why for appointment starting 1970-10-14T08:00:00.000Z hour is shifted by API to 09:00:00+01:00 and if I shift start date to year 2000 it is shifted to 10:00:00+02:00 ?  When I check how both events looks in Google they are starting on different hours, and in my opinion should start the same hour (as only year was changed)

```
var e1 = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();
e1.Summary = "Birthday1";
e1.Start = new EventDateTime();
e1.End = new EventDateTime();
e1.Start.DateTime = new DateTime(1970, 10, 14, 10, 0, 0);
e1.End.DateTime = new DateTime(1970, 10, 14, 11, 0, 0);
e1.Start.TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw";
e1.End.TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw";
e1.Recurrence = new List<String>();
e1.Recurrence.Add("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=14;BYMONTH=10");

Assert.AreEqual("1970-10-14T08:00:00.000Z", e1.Start.DateTimeRaw);
var c1 = service.Insert(e1, primaryCalendar.Id).Execute();
Assert.AreEqual("1970-10-14T09:00:00+01:00", c1.Start.DateTimeRaw); // 09:00:00+01:00 

var e2 = new Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event();
e2.Summary = "Birthday2";
e2.Start = new EventDateTime();
e2.End = new EventDateTime();
e2.Start.DateTime = new DateTime(2000, 10, 14, 10, 0, 0);
e2.End.DateTime = new DateTime(2000, 10, 14, 11, 0, 0);
e2.Start.TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw";
e2.End.TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw";
e2.Recurrence = new List<String>();
e2.Recurrence.Add("RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=14;BYMONTH=10");

Assert.AreEqual("2000-10-14T08:00:00.000Z", e2.Start.DateTimeRaw);
var c2 = service.Insert(e2, primaryCalendar.Id).Execute();
Assert.AreEqual("2000-10-14T10:00:00+02:00", c2.Start.DateTimeRaw); //10:00:00+02:00
```

And I would like to know what I need to do to save old recurring appointments correctly to Google? Should I have some separate logic which depends on year?

Many thanks for help!

Comment: Want to test it using say January instead. I am wondering if this is a daylight savings time issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents), its start and end fields must define the first occurrence and its recurrence field defines how the event should be repeated over time.

You can try this [sample](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/recurringevents) based on the documentation. Here, I created an event every 10am-11am of Oct. 14 starting this year 2016. It will repeat every year as stated in the rule. If will only stop if you add `UNTIL=[yearmmdd]` in the rule.

```
Event event = new Event()
{
    Summary = "Appointment",
    Location = "Somewhere",
    Start = new EventDateTime() {
        DateTime = new DateTime("2016-10-14T10:00:00")
        TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw"
    },
    End = new EventDateTime() {
        DateTime = new DateTime("2016-10-14T11:00:00")
        TimeZone = "Europe/Warsaw"
    },
    Recurrence = new String[] {
        "RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTHDAY=14;BYMONTH=10"
    },
    Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>()
    {
        new EventAttendee() { Email: "attendeeEmail" },
        // ...
    }
};

Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(event, "primary").Fetch();

Console.WriteLine(recurringEvent.Id);
```

You can also check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/events-calendars#recurring_events) for more sample.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not answering my question,  my problem is that if I create recurring event starting years ago (like start in 1970) and another one starting recently then despite I specify the same start time (like 10am)  in result I have shifted hours